# A Filipino Programmer Getting Permanent Residency In California

Tags: usa, visa

So here is the situation: The Philippines as it is doesn't provide much hope for software developers like me. Specially being a Game Developer. There are very few gaming companies in the Philippines or if not, there is none at all.

Looking for opportunities abroad. A gaming company based on Mt. View California took interest in my application.

Now I was thinking of accepting the job and moving there. Is it possible to (after 5 or more years) be able to apply for citizenship? I was thinking that maybe I could take my parents with me (soon), considering I'm the only child I wish to take care of them.

> Yes. I know there is a very long and almost impossible process to get through all this. I just want to know if there is hope in bringing my parents there after a few years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite a long path to get permanent residency (a.k.a the Green Card) and citizenship:

1. First you must find a company willing to sponsor [H1B visa](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/h-1b-specialty-occupations-dod-cooperative-research-and-development-project-workers-and-fashion-models) for you.
2. You must get all documents translated and verified if necessary to have the application ready by 1st of April.
3. You have be lucky enough to be selected in the lottery, for example [for FY2015 there where 172,000 applicants for 65,000 visas](http://www.uscis.gov/news/uscis-reaches-fy-2015-h-1b-cap-0).
4. If you made it this far, you could start working in US in October 2015.
5. General recommendation is to start applying for green card after one year, processing time varies, but generally is between half-year and year-and-half. Not counting the backlog.
6. Since you're Filipino, you'd be dealing with [5 years of processing backlog](http://www.workpermit.com/news/2014-06-30/us-immigration-latest-green-card-priority-dates).
7. With luck by 2022 you'd have green card. Now you'd have to wait at least 5 years to apply for citizenship.
8. You'd [apply for citizenship](http://www.uscis.gov/n-400) and after just few months processing with luck you'd get it.

Overall, with lot of luck if you'd start now, you could become US citizen in 2028-2030.

Comment: As for the H1B visa, yes that would be taken care of by the company in California.

Comment: Also, at what stage do I get to bring my parents with me there? Should I wait until I'm a resident? Or is when applying for the greencard (and include my parents) possible?

Comment: @majidarif Family based immigration to the US is an entirely different matter and should be separated from H1 immigration.

Comment: I agree, that's whole different subject. Something also worth considering is financial side of things (like the cost of healthcare in US).

Comment: @majidarif You can't sponsor parents as a US permanent resident. You have to be a citizen.